# UIWebView in UIScrollView with autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiwebview, autolayout

I am having lots of trouble with this setup. So basically I am displaying some labels with variable height then a button and at the end of the view i need a WebView to display some HTML formatted text.

I resize the web view height constraint when the content is loaded as follows.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        nContentViewHeight.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
}
```

When the view is first loaded, this works perfectly. The scrolling is good and all the web view content is visible.

But when I rotate the device I don't know how to properly resize the web view. I tried loading the content again in

```
override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation)
```

so that `webViewDidFinishLoad` would trigger again and resize the web view. But that doesn't work at all because the contentSize of the scrollview inside the web view doesn't change.

Not knowing why I attempted very ugly solution and that is this:

```
func fitWebAndScrollView(){
    let newRect = CGRectMake(nContentWebView.frame.minX, nContentWebView.frame.minY, self.view.frame.width, 10)
    let newWebView = UIWebView(frame: newRect)
    newWebView.delegate = self
    newWebView.tag = -12
    newWebView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
    self.view.addSubview(newWebView)
    newWebView.loadHTMLString(contentHtml, baseURL: nil)
}

override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    fitWebAndScrollView()
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    nContentViewHeight.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
    if webView.tag == -12 {
        webView.removeFromSuperview()
        nContentViewHeight.constant *= 1.1 // longer the content is more of it is clipped
    }
}
```

And this sort of works, but in some instance the bottom of the WebView content is clipped as if the inner scrollview content size is calculated incorrectly.

Has anybody dealt with this before? I always assumed that this sort of thing wasn't an extra special use case.

Thank you for your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aright so I managed to solve it this way

```
func fitWebAndScrollView(){
    if let strH = nContentWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById(\"cnt\").offsetHeight;"),
    numH = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(strH){
        nContentViewHeight.constant = CGFloat(numH)+20
    }
}

override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    fitWebAndScrollView()
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    fitWebAndScrollView()
}
```

The problem was actually with the HTML code I was using as a wrapper.

```
let htmlWrapperString = "<html><head>\n<style type=\"text/css\">body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}</style></head><body><div id=\"cnt\">%@</div></body></html>"
```

So before I didn't have that wrapping div in the body and when I queried the height of body tag it always returned the whole view port size and not just the text height that was in body.

Now it works reliably.

Comment: What I still don't get is why you want the content height affecting the height of the webview? If your webview is smaller than the content, it has its own scrollview automatically available to scroll the content.

Comment: I needed to display variable amount of HTML formatted text in the web view, meaning I wanted it to look and behave just like a label. I disable the scrolling feature of the web view. So the whole view is scrollable and not only the web view.
[Storyboard](http://oi57.tinypic.com/5cd75i.jpg)
From the image it should be apparent what i needed to achieve.

Comment: Ok, then the external scrollview does make sense. You'll want to disable scrolling on the webview's internal scrollview, though, and probably disable user interaction for the whole view. Then, assuming you control the content displayed (i.e., it's not an arbitrary website), it might even work reasonably well; in our app ("Random - the app") we actually use a similar trick to show content preview cards, only it's not a scrollview but a custom view with a pan gesture recogniser. You can also help yourself by designing the CSS in a way that behaves predictably when you change the size.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if the code is really as shown, you are assigning the *width* of the content to the *height* constant. This would definitely cause the issue. (Apparently it is not as shown; please show actual code instead of typing in new "similar" code into the question…)

Second, it is not a very reliable way to detect the content height by only doing it in `webViewDidFinishLoad`. On some sites it may take a long time before this is actually called but the content may still be usable, and of course any action by the user in the browser may change it, and many websites append more content to the end of the page on the fly (e.g., as the user scrolls down).

Also, I hope you realize that `scrollView.contentSize` is the size of the content itself (not the visible part), and its height won't change on rotation unless the width is changed in a way that makes the content layout change.

Overall I think you may be trying to do something that `UIWebView` is simply not suited for. You should only autolayout the size of the webview itself, not have it inside an external `UIScrollView` (if I read the title correctly and that's what you are doing). Its inner `scrollView` will then handle the content scrolling for you automatically, instead of conflicting with your external scrollView. You can set yourself up as the delegate of the inner scrollview if you need to react to events from it, etc.

To resize the `UIWebView` itself on rotation, set up constraints to bind the distance from each of its edges to the surrounding views (or use the simpler `autoresizingMask`). There should be no need to do anything in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` (and if you do need manual layout, do it in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and/or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`).

Comment: Thank you for you response. That first part was just a typo, its not what was causing the issue, i just forgot to fix it when copying code (I will correct it so it's not confusing).
I do realise that contentSize is the size of the actual content. And when the screen rotates the height of that changes. But it never did, that is why I was always creating new WebViews cause the first time it did the sizing it got it semi correct.

But I managed to find the solution after i posted the question (this always happens to me!) and i will post it shortly.

Thanks